# Failing to render my search to the browser

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter my todos based on their status i.e; complete and incomplete. I have written down all the code that is required to get it but I get this kind of error:

```
index.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at index.js:29
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at renderTodos (index.js:28)
    at index.js:47
```

Here is my actual code to help me render the filtered todos to the browser:

```
const todos = [
  {
    todo: "Pray",
    status: "false",
  },
  {
    todo: "Shower",
    status: "true",
  },
  {
    todo: "Eat",
    status: "true",
  },
  {
    todo: "Run",
    status: "false",
  },
  {
    todo: "Work",
    status: "false",
  },
];

const filters = {
  searchText: "",
};
const renderTodos = function (todos, filters) {
  const filteredTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
    return todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase());
  });
  const incompleteTodos = filteredTodos.filter(function (todo) {
    return !todo.status;
  });

  document.querySelector("#todos").innerHTML = "";
  const summary = document.createElement("h1");
  summary.textContent = `You have ${incompleteTodos.length} todos left`;
  document.querySelector("#todos").appendChild(summary);

  todos.forEach(function (todo) {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = todo.text;
    document.querySelector("#todos").appendChild(p);
  });
};

renderTodos(todos, filters);

document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  filters.searchText = e.target.value;
  renderTodos(todos, filters);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `todo` object does not have a `text` property but just `status` and `todo`; you probably wanted to filter by `todo`:

```
const filteredTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
    return todo.todo.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the error is in the line :-
`return todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase());`

Here you're trying to access the text property of the todo object, which is not available in the objects of the `todos` array. It only has `todo` and `status` property.

so the code will look like this...

```
return todo.todo.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase());
```